# Git keep file in Local branches but remove from repo

Tags: git, github

I thought there would be  an obvious solution but can't seem to find it. I have a repo with a configfile that changes from machine to machine -

I I do `git rm --cached myconfig.conf` and make a file called `myconcif.template.conf` - this mostly works, but if I switch branches locally and then switch back `myconfig.conf` ends up getting removed.

What I want is to be able to keep `myconfig.conf` changes committed locally, but have them ignored for both repository push and pull.

Answer (score 1):

After doing `git rm --cached myconfig.conf` you need to add it to the `.ignore` file.

Adding it to the ignore file means that the file will be ignored not only for pull and push, but for switching branches too.

If you want local myconfig.conf to change with each branch without having it versioned, I'm afraid you can't.

**Edit**: sometimes git seems to be stubborn about this procedure, so a dirty workaround is just:

- Copy the file to another location out of the repo.
- Delete it with git rm
- Add it to the .gitignore
- Commit and push the deletion and the changed .gitinore
- Do the same in all your working branches locally and in the repo
- Make sure all your branches are in sync with the remote
- When you're sure the file isn't coming back after pulling or switching branches, you can safely move the copied version to your repo folder.

Comment: It is in .gitignore, and it definitely gets removed when i checkout to another branch and back. Also yes the later would be best. I'd want it versioned but never over-written on pull and never pushed on push.